# Animation Listener works fine in emulator but not on phone (Samsung s4)

Tags: android, animation, view, android-animation, listeners

SO I have an animation Listener that's attached to a `button`s `onClick` via a method. The animation is just a simple Alpha animation (fade in and fade out) of a certain view and it works fine on the emulator but it doesn't work on the phone (Samsung s4). The thing is that when the animation is called text fades out, the text changes, and then it fades back in with new text. The text changes just fine but there is no animation.

Below is the method with the listener and i don't know if this helps but in another activity in the app I have a view do some fade it with just some AnimationUtils (with an xml i made) and that one works fine...Any help is much appreciated, This is like the last thing I have to do.

```
private void AnimationMethodForTextView(final TextView TitleArea, final int explanation){
    ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TitleArea, "alpha", 1.0f, 0.0f);
    fadeOut.setDuration(1000);

    final ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(TitleArea, "alpha", 0.0f, 1.0f);
    fadeIn.setDuration(1000);





    fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            TitleArea.setText(explanation);
            TitleArea.scrollTo(0, 0);
            fadeIn.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Is animation turned off in the developer settings?

Comment: I did and it solved the problem! will everybody have to do that if they download this app and want to have the animations? @Whitney

Comment: No they shouldn't have to. Most people don't enable developer settings on their devices unless they are a developer and all the devices I've enabled have it default set to on, so I would guess yours got toggled to off somehow.